# google apps script: get gmail jpg attachments & insert them into google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

The code finds all the jpg's from a sender and then creates an array with those images and then is supposed to insert the received images into the cells of the sheet.

Instead, the code inserts the word Blog into the cells instead of the images.

I've tried several methods to solve the problem but have not had any luck.

```
function importEmailsWithJPGs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var emailAddress = "a@gmail.com";

  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:" + emailAddress + " filename:jpg");
  var attachments;
  var date;
  
  var rowData = {};
  
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      attachments = messages[j].getAttachments();
      date = messages[j].getDate();
      var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
      
      if (!rowData[dateString]) {
        rowData[dateString] = [date];
      }
      
      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
        if (attachments[k].getContentType().indexOf("image/jpeg") !== -1) {
         
         //var image = attachments[k].getAs('image/jpeg');
         // var imageName = attachments[k].getName();
         // var blob = new Blob([image], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
         // rowData[dateString].push(blob);
          //var image = attachments[k].getAs('image/jpeg');
        
         // var imageName = attachments[k].getName();
         // var byteArray = image.getBytes();
         // var base64EncodedImage = Utilities.base64Encode(byteArray);
         // var blob = Utilities.newBlob(base64EncodedImage, 'image/jpeg', imageName);
         // rowData[dateString].push(blob);

          var image = attachments[k].copyBlob();
          var imageName = attachments[k].getName();
          var blob = Utilities.newBlob(image.getBytes(), 'image/jpeg', imageName);
          rowData[dateString].push(blob);



        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  for (var key in rowData) {
    sheet.appendRow(rowData[key]);
  }
  
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
      var value = data[i][j];
       if (value && value.getBytes) {
        //var image = value;
        var image = value.getAs('image/jpeg');

        //var imageData = new Uint8Array(image.getBytes());
        var cellWidth = cell.getWidth();
        var cellHeight = cell.getHeight();
        var imageWidth = image.getWidth();
        var imageHeight = image.getHeight();
        var ratio = Math.min(cellWidth / imageWidth, cellHeight / imageHeight);
        cell.setValue("");
       // cell.setImageData(imageData);
       cell.setImageData(image);
        }      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From your showing script and your current issue of `Instead, the code inserts the word Blog into the cells instead of the images.`, I guessed that your current issue is from `sheet.appendRow(rowData[key]);`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, is your question to resolve this part? Because I think that after that line of `var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`, I think that `value && value.getBytes` is always false. Because, `value.getBytes` is undefined, and also, there is no method of `setImageData` in Class Range at `cell.setImageData(image);`. What will you do about this? I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @tanaike appendRow works because I see rows populated with dates and and the word Blog in cells. however, you are correct. something is wrong with the next part. it never enters this part  for (var j = 1; j < data[i].length; j++)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modification point by guessing your expected result. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- First, I think that the reason that the text of `Blob` is put to the cell is due to that `appendRow` cannot put the image blob to the cell.
- After that line of `var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`, I think that `value && value.getBytes` is always false. Because, `value.getBytes` is undefined, and also, there is no method of `setImageData` in Class Range at `cell.setImageData(image);`. And, an error occurs at `value.getAs('image/jpeg')` because `value` has no method.

Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand the relationship between `for (var key in rowData) { sheet.appendRow(rowData[key]); }` and the script below `var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`. But, if you want to just put the image data from the image blob to the cells instead of the text of `Blob`, how about the following modification?

In this modification, a Google Apps Script library is used. Because in the current stage, unfortunately, the image blob cannot be directly put into a cell. So, I created this library. In order to use the following modified script, please do the following flow.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

You can see how to install it at https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#how-to-install. (Author of this library: me)

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

[Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced?hl=ja#enable_advanced_services).

#### 3. Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

##### From:

```js
for (var key in rowData) {
  sheet.appendRow(rowData[key]);
}

var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
    var value = data[i][j];
     if (value && value.getBytes) {
      //var image = value;
      var image = value.getAs('image/jpeg');

      //var imageData = new Uint8Array(image.getBytes());
      var cellWidth = cell.getWidth();
      var cellHeight = cell.getHeight();
      var imageWidth = image.getWidth();
      var imageHeight = image.getHeight();
      var ratio = Math.min(cellWidth / imageWidth, cellHeight / imageHeight);
      cell.setValue("");
     // cell.setImageData(imageData);
     cell.setImageData(image);
      }      
  }
}
```

##### To:

```js
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var v = Object.values(rowData);
var values = v.map(([a]) => [a]);
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
var obj = v.map(([, blob], i) => ({ blob, range: { row: lastRow + i + 1, column: 2 } }));
DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(sheet.getParent().getId()).getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName()).insertImage(obj);
```

- When this script is run, the text value and the image data are put into the columns "A" and "B", respectively.

### Reference:

- [DocsServiceApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)